# VSCode keyboard shortcuts for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

Is there a way to add VSCode as an option under Android Studio's keymap settings?

Under `File` -> `Settings...` -> `Keymap`
[image]

There are many other options listed, however none of them are even similar to VSCode

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was unable to find anybody else who had done this, so I created my own

https://github.com/meadowsjared/VSCode-keybindings-for-Android-Studio

If you click the GitHub link above, it includes both instructions
and you can also download the jar file you'll need (just hit `Clone or download`)

note: this was created for windows

Comment: After importing, I realized these are Windows keybindings lol.

Comment: I don't get it. I installed this and made sure it is selected, but it doesn't seem to work. Ctrl+arrows doesn't nagivate around in the code, Ctrl+P doesn't pop the file search dialog....

Answer (score 61):

Actually, JetBrains has created an official `VSCode Keymap` plugin in 2019 to get the Visual Studio Code keymap into Android Studio, you just need to download it first:

[image: Installing VSCode keymap from plugins dialog]

After that you can select the keymap `VSCode` in the keymap settings.

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12062-vscode-keymap