# Import Android studio shortcuts in VSCode

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code

Is there any way I can export/use Android Studio shortcuts to/in VSCode? I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48967487/vscode-keyboard-shortcuts-for-android-studio) but it does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much different the Android Studio shortcuts are from the Intellij ones, but if they're pretty much the same, you could install the Redhat Java extension, which will prompt you if you want to use Intellij shortcuts. From there, you could proceed to add any missing Android Studio shortcuts manually.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? That might help other people come up with a better solution then. What exactly happened, are the shortcuts wrong, or did they not get imported as well?

Comment: A quick Search for a keymap lead me to this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings

Comment: Yeah sure (to be honest I am very new to VSCode), I downloaded the plugin, and it got installed, now on Android Studio if I keep pressing `//`, it comments current line and move cursor to next, but on VSCode, it simply comments/uncomments current line, it never moves to the next line.

Comment: Could `cmd/ctrl + /` do that for you?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, actually I was using `cmd` + `/`